# Como capturar foto da câmera e apagar da galeria

Tags: android

Estou obtendo a imagem da câmera e salvando no banco. Pegar a imagem é código bem difundido, não tem nada de novo. Contudo a imagem fica também na galeria, e eu gostaria de excluir ela, uma vez que já tenho ela salva no banco SQLite, mas não sei como.

Answer (score 0):

Eu vejo duas alternativas:

1) você criar um diretório exclusivo pra sua aplicação e armazenar todas as fotos, mantendo o histórico no aparelho - isso é legal quando as fotos podem ser consultadas (armazenamento em *cache*). Nesse caso aconselho você criar um arquivo `.nomedia` pra que as imagens não apareçam mais na galeria e dificultem que o usuário delete-as.

2) caso prefira deletar após a gravação na base, você pode excluir o arquivo (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5486529/delete-file-from-internal-storage). Só atenta pra não deletar antes da gravação

Comment: Olá Linhares boa tarde, meu valeu ai pela interação, sobre deletar antes não, eu faço o procedimento comum ou seja capturo e jogo no imageView com  dimensões redefinidas dela que eu jogo no SQLite, bem vou ver sua sugestão, Obrigado.